# Versioning for binding redirect in app.config .Net

Tags: binding, version, app-config, .net-assembly, assembly-binding-redirect

I have binding redirect section in my app.config file.

```
<dependentAssembly>
 <assemblyIdentity name="assemblyName" publicKeyToken="xxxxxxx" culture="neutral"/>
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.3.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

My purpose is to redirect any assembly in range of 0.0.0.0 and 2.3.0.0 to version 2.3.0.0. The question is that I don't understand and can't find any articles how binding redirection works for third and fourth block of version (xx.yy.zz.mmmm -> question about zz.mmmm).

Am I right assuming that since I have set zz.mmmm to zero, I'm saying that everything besides major and minor version don't metter and the highest version will be taken and my code covers following situation?

1. I have two versions. 1.3.8.5918 and 2.3.9.7859. According to my code 1.3.8.5918 will be redirected to 2.3.9.7859?
2. I have two versions. 2.2.0.1245 and 2.3.8.9865. According to my code 2.2.0.1245 will be redirected to 2.3.8.9865?
3. The last one. I'm not sure whether it is relevant for me, but since I'm trying to figure out how it works, what if I have 
   two versions. 2.3.8.5918 and 2.3.9.7859. Will 2.3.8.5918 be redirected to 2.3.9.7859 since for my "binding redirect rule" these two versions are the same i.e. "unspecified"?

Thanks for any information